# How to flash firmware upgrade to Thinkpad Ultra Docking Station on Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, updates, firmware, docking-station

I need to update the firmware of a **Thinkpad Ultra Docking Station** to V3.3.1, which has been [released last year](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/DS505699). I got no laptop running Windows 7/8/10 and Lenovo does not provide this update via [LVFS](https://fwupd.org/), but only as an `.exe` file.

Is it possible to flash the firmware update onto the dock under Linux? Or does somebody know another way to update the dock's firmware?

A few approaches I am considering:

- <strike>Maybe I could create a Windows 10 USB recovery drive, boot it, fire up a shell and then install the update.</strike>
- Another option would be to create a Windows Preinstallation Environment (PE), flash it to an USB drive, boot it and then run the update. However, all tutorials I found on how to create a PE seem to be outdated.
- Inside a VirtualBox VM I have a Windows 10 Pro 2004 running. Maybe it is somehow possible to pass-through the dock to this VM to flash the update?
- I have not tried, but am 99.9999% sure that any approach based on WINE will not work.

**What I already tried so far:**

- Leveraging the Windows 10 Pro 2004 VM's "Recovery Media Creator" tool, I crafted an USB recovery drive, copied the firmware onto the USB drive and tried to run it, but unfortunately without success:
  [image: Error message]
  I also tried the "[Firmware Update Tool for Enterprise Deploy](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/de/en/downloads/ds540663)" and followed the instructions for "*Silent deployment in other environment*" but ended up with the same error.

There are [two](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Displays-Options-and-Accessories/Lenovo-UltraDock-firmware-update-when-you-re-not-running-Windows/m-p/4079732) [threads](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Displays-Options-and-Accessories/Thinkpad-Thunderbolt-3-dock-firmware-update-Linux/m-p/4558777?page=1) over at the Lenovo forums regarding firmware updates of an older / another docking station, but neither of them with an accepted solution.

Comment: Firmware for what?

Comment: For a Thinkpad Ultra Dock, like I wrote at the title and at the question and for what I included a link to the firmware download page.

Comment: OK, for the dock itself. If there is not a linux flasher provided by Lenovo then there is no way to do it, it is intended to be executed under a Windows 10 environment, You could create a Windows 10 system repair disc (can be done on any W10 PC as long as it is the same bit version 64 or 32), this will get you a windows environment.

Comment: @Moab the system-repair-disc-approach was not successful (see extended question). Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Many possibilities for running firmware update on Linux. Use one from the article [Flashing BIOS from Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux). There is no need for a full Windows version, just for DOS, for example FreeDOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to all your answers, I finally was able to install the update:

1. Downloaded Windows 10 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).
2. Created a new Windows 10 VM in VirtualBox on a 14 GB VDI virtual disk.
3. Installed Windows 10 Pro 2004 (Selected "I don't have a product key" and disconnected the virtual network adapter to be able to create a local account)
   [image: Screenshot Windows 10 Install]
4. Reattached the virtual network adapter and downloaded the [Firmware Update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/DS505699) as well as the [Intel Graphics Driver](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/de/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t480-type-20l5-20l6/downloads/driver-list/component?name=Display%20and%20Video%20Graphics).
5. Converted VDI virtual disk to raw image:
   `vbox-img convert --srcfilename ~/VBoxVMs/Windows\ 10\ USB/Windows\ 10\ USB.vdi --dstfilename ~/usb.hdd --srcformat VDI --dstformat RAW`
6. Bought 16 GiB USB drive (On this occasion I want to emphasize how much I hate to buy hardware to solve a software issue).
7. `dd`'ed the raw image onto the USB drive: `sudo dd status=progress if=~/usb.hdd of=/dev/sdb bs=512K`
8. Entered UEFI firmware setup, switched boot mode to "Legacy only", enabled "CSM support" and changed boot priority to boot from USB.
9. Booted into Windows 10 from USB drive (Did *not* use a USB port of the docking station, but of the laptop).
10. Installed Intel Graphics driver (Without it the update will not find the current `DP Hub` and `PD Control` version and finally raise the following error: *"Update timeout, please remove all devices from the Dock, and reboot computer to try again."*).
11. Run the firmware update
    [image: Screenshot of firmware update]
12. Entered UEFI firmware setup and reverted settings.

Please be aware that at least with Win10_20H2_English_x64.iso this procedure won't quite work any longer as Microsoft now switches to their so-called S mode when booting a previously VirtualBox provisioned image. Unfortunately, in S mode one can neither install the required graphics drivers nor launch the docking station update!

Comment: You don't need windows for that.

Comment: @0andriy then please share with us how it works without windows.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, ended up doing the same after seeing it. As I have access to an older Windows computer I found it easier to rather just use rufus to make a "Windows on the go" drive. At some point rufus got support for making "Windows on the go" drives directly so it's as easy as just selecting the ISO, which drive and hit go. rufus also makes it bootable w/UEFI so you won't need to change the BIOS settings for it to work - just as an alternative to your great guide over here.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something...

If you can stand to format the existing drive or have a spare HDD  Just install windows 10 preform the upgrade, then switch back to your Linux installation. You do not need a key to install a trial copy of windows 10. Just select "I don't have a key" while installing.

Answer (score 1):

If Lenovo doesn't provide the firmware in a bootable ISO or other system-neutral format (and shame on them), then your best bet in terms of a) foolproof and b) not wasting your valuable time, is probably to install a copy of windows on an external drive (or restore the system to an external drive if you still have the factory restore files).  Boot from that drive, make sure you've got all the drivers needed so the firmware can see the dock, then run the firmware update within Windows.  You can skip typing in the activation key and still have a usable system that will let you get the firmware patched.

Use Windows 7 or 8 if your laptop supports it, lately 10 *requires* the creation of a Microsoft account, and lots of personal information like your phone number (!) before it will let you get past setup to the desktop.

Comment: Awarded the bounty to you for the most comprehensive answer, however the solution turned out to be more complex: https://superuser.com/a/1572589/395378